# Why 13 is special for the Mazur's theorem on torsion of elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm studying the proof of Mazur's theorem on the torsion of elliptic curves. He first show that, for a prime $N > 7$ **and $N\neq 13$**, there's no elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a rational point of order $N$. The proof uses Jacobian $J_{0}(N)$ of modular curve $X_{0}(N)$, and when $N = 13$, $X_{0}(13) \simeq \mathbb{P}^{1}$ so that $J_{0}(13)$ is trivial. This gives a reason to treat $N=13$ case separately.

The proof for $N = 13$ can be found in Mazur and Tate's paper *Points of order 13 on elliptic curves*, and you can also find it in [Snowden's lecture note](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Easnowden/teaching/2013/679/L22.html). To show that there's no non-cuspidal points on $X_{1}(13)$ which are rational over $\mathbb{Q}$, they consider an action of so-called *twisted dihedral group* on $X_{1}(13)$. They show that, under the embedding $X_{1}(13)(\mathbb{C}) \hookrightarrow J_{1}(13)(\mathbb{C})$, the image of modular curve intersects with $J_{1}(13)(\mathbb{Q})_{\mathrm{tors}}$ only at the cuspidal points, so that it is enough to show that $J_{1}(13)(\mathbb{Q})$ has rank 0.

I think I don't get why the number $N=13$ is special for the proof, and I wonder if the method of the proof can be also applied to other $N$'s. The Mazur and Tate's paper is mentioning about forthcoming work of D. Kubert that seems to study $X_{1}(N)$ for other $N$'s, but I can't find the paper they mentioned.

Comment: Don't you have $\operatorname{rank}J_1(N)(\mathbb{Q})>0$ for all sufficiently large prime $N$ (IIRC it has something to do with the monster group)?

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for pointing it out. So if we can use the same proof technique that used for $N=13$ to other $N$'s, then $N$ might be *small*. I wonder if there even exists a single $N\neq 13$ that we can apply similar method.